How can I rearrange my test to allow me to access the referral
I have a simple request spec and am trying to test that :notify_referrer is called.
  def create
    @referral = Referral.new(referral_params)

    if @referral.save
      @referral.notify_referrer
      @referral.create_referral_created_event

      render json: @referral, status: :created
    else
      render json: @referral.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

I run into a problem because I can't access assigns(:referral) before the test runs.  How else can I write this to allow my test to pass?  I undestand you should avoid allow_any_instance_of so I am looking for another solution.
it 'notifies the referrer' do
  allow(_____).to receive(:notify_referrer)

  post api_referrals_path, params:
  {
    referral: { referrer_id: referrer.id, referred_id: referred.id }
  }, headers: { HTTP_AUTHENTICATION: token }

  expect(assigns(:referral)).to have_received(:notify_referrer)
end


Why "should you avoid allow_any_instance_of"?

@dbugger Because it's recommended by the RSpec team. https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-mocks/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance/

You don't.
Request specs are a thin wrapper around rails integration tests - not controller tests which at one point had an assigns method that could be used to poke inside the controller.
And before you head down that rabbit hole controller test as well as assigns have been depreachiated by both the Rails and RSpec teams for a very long time.

Testing what instance variables are set by your controller is a bad
idea. That's grossly overstepping the boundaries of what the test
should know about. You can test what cookies are set, what HTTP code
is returned, how the view looks, or what mutations happened to the DB,
but testing the innards of the controller is just not a good idea.
- David Heinemeier Hansson

Assigns only ever worked in controller tests as they create an instance of your controller and call the method directly on it. Request/feature/system specs send real HTTP requests to a Rails server instance and it's not even guarenteed to be running in the same thread so the amount of black magic needed to indirectly access its instance variables makes it a very very bad idea.
While avoiding any_instance_of is generally a good idea you're actually reaching for something that is much worse.
So what then?
Test what your controller does - not how it does it. For example does create_referral_created_event have any side effects that you can test?
it 'notifies the referrer' do
  expect do
    post api_referrals_path, params: {
      referral: { referrer_id: referrer.id, referred_id: referred.id }
    }, headers: { HTTP_AUTHENTICATION: token }
  end.to change(FooBarBaz, :count).by(1)
end

This can also be telling you have a code smell and that the method doesn't actually belong in your model which already has plenty of other responisbilities. This is also what the RSpec-Mocks docs hint at when discouraging the use of any_instance:

Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test
is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex.

If you refactor it into for example the service object pattern or an ActiveJob you can simply set an expectation on that collaborator instead of on an instance of the model.
# For lack of a better name
class ReferralCreatedEventJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(referral)
    # ...
  end
end

  def create
    @referral = Referral.new(referral_params)

    if @referral.save
      @referral.notify_referrer # this should be a candidate for refactoring as well
      ReferralCreatedEventJob.perform_now(@referral)
      render json: @referral, status: :created
    else
      render json: @referral.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

it 'notifies the referrer' do
  expect(ReferralCreatedEventJob).to receive(:perform_now)
  post api_referrals_path, params:
  {
    referral: { referrer_id: referrer.id, referred_id: referred.id }
  }, headers: { HTTP_AUTHENTICATION: token }
end

As a last resort you could stub Referral.new to insert a spy but it really isn't any better than any_instance_of.

Thanks for the thorough response.  I rely on services for most things like this however with a one-liner it felt over-the-top.  That being said, I totally agree with you.

Sometimes the line count is irrelevant. Rails models are a glaring example of this. Even with no lines in the class body they do an insane number of things.
